# c# exporting sql data to csv

Tags: c#, sql, csv, streamwriter

When exporting my data from sql to excel, it starts with the second line and not the first. I think I've narrowed down the problem to the streamwriter section of code but can't seem to work out where it's going wrong!
This is the code;

```
public static void ToCsv3(IDataReader myReader, string fileName, bool includeHeaderAsFirstRow)

    {
        const string Separator = ",";
        Stream s = File.Create(fileName + ".txt");
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(s, Encoding.Unicode);


        StringBuilder sb = null;

        if (includeHeaderAsFirstRow)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0; index < myReader.FieldCount; index++)
            {
                if (myReader.GetName(index) != null)
                    sb.Append(myReader.GetName(index));

                if (index < myReader.FieldCount - 1)
                    sb.Append(Separator);
            }
            streamWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        int j = 0;
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();


            for (int index = 0; index < myReader.FieldCount - 1; index++)
            {


                if (!myReader.IsDBNull(index))
                {
                    string value = myReader.GetValue(index).ToString();
                    if (myReader.GetFieldType(index) == typeof(String))
                    {
                        if (value.IndexOf("\"") >= 0)
                            value = value.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
                        if (value.IndexOf(Separator) >= 0)
                            value = "\"" + value + "\"";
                    }
                    if (j != 0)
                    {
                        if (index == 0)
                        {
                            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }
                    sb.Append(value);

                    j = j + 1;
                }


                if (index < myReader.FieldCount - 1)
                    sb.Append(Separator);

            }


           if (!myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.FieldCount - 1))
                sb.Append(myReader.GetValue(myReader.FieldCount).ToString().Replace(Separator, " "));


            streamWriter.Write(sb.ToString());
        }



        myReader.Close();
        streamWriter.Close();


    }
```

Comment: Is the issue that the header you are generating is not being written to the file when `includeHeaderAsFirstRow` is `true` or is it that data is being written to the file starting at line 2 and not line 1 even if it's the header?

Comment: It writes the header, then skips the next line (the first line of data) and writes from the second line of data in the table/database

Comment: Could it be, that the DataReader moved one row *before* you pass it in?

Comment: Is it possible that the call to `streamWriter.Write(sb.ToString())` has written an empty `string`? It certainly looks as though it may be possible without knowing your DB fields and data returned.

Comment: @RebeccaJones, Is there no line at all or an empty line, or a line with separators but not data? Can you find out, what data **should** appear in the first row?

Comment: Also, as a side note, this code (after being corrected) would only work with specific data and fail in most (ie: one that has varbinary, xml, json, datetime ... type data). For excel, it would be much easier to directly create an xls or xlsx using a collection with Epplus on codeproject (or Excel automation with a QueryTables.Add() method. CSV is certainly not a good choice to get data to excel (except for simple and small data).

Comment: @Shnugo There should be a line there, it starts from the second line as if it was the first. I think the problem occurs after "int j = 0" but not sure after that, it might be reading from the second line in the database?

Comment: @StephenRoss the first 'code' streamWriter.Write(sb.ToString()) writes the header and the second one writes each line out (I think)

Comment: @CetinBasoz I'm unsure what you mean by this, the header is overwriting the first row of table? If I don't run the part creating the headers it still doesn't write in the first line of data, just skips to the second line.
In this case for me it's very specific, I create the csv, remove the blank last line, zip the file and then email it (but the problem arises here)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific on which call to `streamWriter.Write(...)`. I am meaning the call before the closing bracket of the `while` statement where you are writing out your data. It's possible that you could write out the header then not actually add any data to the `StringBuilder` in the `while` loop, possibly outputting an empty string before adding an `Environment.NewLine`. It would depend on what the database returned.

Comment: I was not very careful in reading your code, There is an error along the lines:
if (!myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.FieldCount - 1))
                sb.Append(myReader.GetValue(myReader.FieldCount).ToString().Replace(Separator, " "));

it should be myReader.GetValue(myReader.FieldCount-1). Other than that this is working right for me without dropping any lines.

Comment: @CetinBasoz trying that unfortunate brings the same results, truly am stumped with this! Breaking it down it doesn't seem to be reading the first line, but can not see why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather decompose the solution into creating CSV and saving it to the file:

```
public static IEnumerable<String> ToCsv(IDataReader reader, 
  Boolean includeHeaderAsFirstRow, 
  Char separator = ',',  
  Char quotation = '"') {

  if (null == reader)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");

  String qt = quotation.ToString(); 

  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

  if (includeHeaderAsFirstRow) {
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; ++i) {
      if (i > 0)
        Sb.Append(separator);

      String name = reader.GetName(i);

      if (name.Contains(separator) || name.Contains(quotation))
        name = qt + name.Replace(qt, qt + qt) + qt;

      Sb.Append(name);
    }

    yield return Sb.ToString();
  }

  while (reader.Read()) {
    Sb.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; ++i) {
      if (i > 0)
        Sb.Append(separator);

      if (!reader.IsDBNull(i)) {
        String item = Convert.ToString(reader[i]);

        if (item.Contains(separator) || item.Contains(quotation))
          item = qt + item.Replace(qt, qt + qt) + qt;

        Sb.Append(item);
      }
    }

    yield return Sb.ToString();
  }
}

public static void CsvToFile(String fileName, 
  IDataReader reader, 
  Char separator = ',',  
  Char quotation = '"') {

  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(fileName)))
    fileName += ".txt"; // ".csv" looks better here

  File.WriteAllLines(fileName, ToCsv(reader, separator, quotation));
}
```

Comment: Actually this works when changing how I called the includeHeaderAsFirstRow to bool! Still puzzled to why my original isn't working but this does the job (after removing the blank last line created afterwards!). thank you